# Adding "Existing website..." in Visual Studio points to wrong folder

Tags: visual-studio, iis, visual-sourcesafe

Visual Studio 2005

We have a solution that was once connected to VSS.

At some point the "Working folder" in VSS was changed from wwwroot to the Projects folder. We don't know how this happened, but ended up disconnecting the site and solution from VSS. We do not need to get it back into VSS.

Folders:

- Projects/SolutionsFolder1/Solution.sln [contains the solution file]
- Projects/SolutionsFolder1/TestSite/ [contains a copy of the code - don't know how it was created]
- wwwroot/TestSite [contains the live code that we want to point to]

We've removed the website from the solution, and deleted the TestSite folder from the Projects folder as it was writing to the incorrect directory. When we attempt to add it back as an IIS site, we get a message

```
Unable to open the Web 'http://localhost/TestSite'. The Web 'http://localhost/TestSite' does not exist
```

- When we add existing website, and select TestSite from the list, we get a "is not marked as an application in IIS. Do you want to open it anyway?" However the folder is configured as an application in IIS
- When we Browse the site in IIS it is pointing to the correct wwwroot
  directory.
- When we add the TestSite folder back to the Projects folder, we're able to add the site. This is not acceptable as we want it to point to the wwwroot version
- I should note that we have 3 other solutions set up with websites in IIS and they are working properly.

It is very strange. VS has the site mapped somewhere but we can't find where. VSS doesn't show the folder at all.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!!

EDIT: Things we've tried so far

1. Clear VS cache ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520593/how-do-you-clear-your-visual-studio-cache-on-windows-vista))
2. Delete SUO file ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673290/visual-studio-retrieving-an-incorrect-path-to-a-project-from-somewhere))
3. Create a new clean solution not connected to VSS, and attempt to add IIS webstie

Answer (score 0):

It seems the website "TestSite" in your IIS is not configured as an application while the wwwroot directory is. To confirm that, please locate TestSite node in your IIS and check if you can find menu "Convert to Application" in the right-click menus.