# Incorrect Website Mapping in local folder from TFS

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, tfs-2005

Somehow in TFS, in the ESQwire service solution website **ESQwireService. Host** has been moved from the TFS Path (In TFS folder structure is showing correct)

```
$/ESQwire/Dev/ESQwireService/ESQwireService/Tests/ESQwireService. Host
```

But when I get the latest version from TFS, website ESQwireService. Host is showing under wrong path i.e

```
C:\ANitha_2\Dev\ESQwireService\ESQwireService\ESQwireService. Host
```

I had removed mapping from tfs on folder ESQwireService. Host and after I get latest version, ESQwireService. Host is there in correct path as in TFS.
But when I try  to open the solution, its asks me that "New projects are added to the solution recently do you to open? (because there are some dependent projects are added) . When I click OK ESQwireService. Host is moving back to the wrong path i.e

```
C:\ANitha_2\Dev\ESQwireService\ESQwireService\ESQwireService. Host
```

the correct path should be same as TFS path

```
C:\ANitha_2\Dev\ESQwireService\ESQwireService\Tests\ESQwireService. Host
```

Answer (score 2):

You must edit work space definition on TFS.
I am writing steps.

Step-1 => open team explorer on visiual studio.

Step-2 => click workspace in workspace combobox.

Step-3 => click on edit button  on window.

Step-4 => change local folder information.

[image]

Comment: Serder,Thanks for your help. As per your suggestion , in workspace I have changed local folder information to the correct path and the website ESQwireService. Host moved back to the correct path. But when I tried to open the solution it gives me an message that C:\ANitha_2\Dev\ESQwireService\ESQwireService\ESQwireService. Host does not exists .i.e solution is trying to load the website from the wrong path. When the solution is loaded ,website ESQwireService. Host shows as unavailable i.e it is referring wrong path. Please help me on this.

Comment: You can remove project files under folder.( C:\ANitha_2\Dev\) and workspace remove on tfs. You have to add mapping  it again.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your Workspace is duplicate or like this. 
Open TFS server and open sql server, select Your Collection 
and check tbl_Workspace and tbl_WorkspaceMapping
you will see dublicate Workzone and path(localItem)

... for solution.
you can delete unwanted workspace and workspacemapping

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673290/visual-studio-retrieving-an-incorrect-path-to-a-project-from-somewhere), the issue could be the **.suo** file.

**Solution summary:**

1. Remove Website from solution.
2. Close Visual Studio
3. Remove .suo file.
4. Open Visual Studio
5. Add Website to solution again.
6. Check bindings -> should be mapped correctly.