# Wrong File Path when Opening a Solution at Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I just wondering around hours and hours and I don't know what's wrong with it.
I have a project, stored in

> **E:\Projects\ProjectA** with the Solution name is **School.sln**

After that I created another project, stored in

> **E:\Projects\ProjectB** with the Solution name is **School.sln**

When I close the **ProjectA** and then open the **ProjectB**, the **file path** in Visual Studio 2015 always referring to **E:\Projects\ProjectA** when it should be referred to **E:\Projects\ProjectB**

I've been googling for this problem, and I found that the solution is :

- Delete the .suo file
- Change the path in application.config

Here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673290/visual-studio-retrieving-an-incorrect-path-to-a-project-from-somewhere) that the problem is similiar with mine, but no luck for me.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Are the two projects created separately, or is one a copy of the other?

Comment: This might be related to the project files rather than the solution files, btw; solutions are just grouped projects, but the projects are what is really executed. Nevermind the .suo files; try removing the .csproj.user file.

Comment: @Nyerguds i think i dont have any .csproj ext in my folder. Created separately , I retrieved those file from SVN (using tortoise SVN), with diferrent URL

Comment: Hm. Well if it exists it'll be right alongside the .csproj file itself. Could be in a project subfolder.

Comment: no luck for me, i've searched in all folder and subfolder @Nyerguds

Comment: Uhh.. if you retrieved them both from SVN, aren't they still copies of the same project? The method of copying doesn't matter; the point here is whether residual files might be the problem. If I were you, I'd try simply recreating the whole solution from scratch and just adding the actual source files into it.

Comment: @Nyerguds thanks for your support, i've found the solution :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay guys,

I've found the solution.
Maybe some people will face the same issue with me someday, and here's the solution.

1. Right click your .sln file (Don't open it or double click it)
2. Open it with notepad or any text editor out there
3. Change the path manually in there
4. Voila, it works!

Thanks all for your contribution

Comment: Dont forget to tick your answer after 48hrs -reputation party!

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks.